# What is this logic function?

Tags: c, computer-science

u and v are unsigned integers

```
for (shift = 0; ((u | v) & 1) == 0; ++shift)
        {
                u >>= 1;
                v >>= 1;
        }
```

I cannot understand ((u | v) & 1) == 0 logic, what if u = 9 and v = 10, what would be the return of the logic function.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this function with a C compiler and running it?

Comment: It shifts both `u` and `v` right until the lowest bit of either one is set.

Comment: Logic aside, that's also an infinite loop waiting to happen.

Comment: As long as `u` and `v` are both even the code divides both by 2. Only odd numbers have their LSB set.  `shift` just counts the number of divisions applied. It's of no use in the code shown, as it lives within the loop only and is not used there.

Comment: @alk `shift` is not declared in the loop (only initialized), so it will be in-scope after the loop terminates.

Comment: @rtx13 absolutly correct. Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `u = 9`, then the binary bit representation of `u` is `...1001`.

If `v = 10`, then the binary bit representation of `v` is `...1010`.

If you binary-or these values using `|`, you will get `...1011`.

If you now binary-and the above value with `1` (i.e. binary `...0001`), you will get `...0001`.

Finally, if you compare binary `...0001` to `0` using `==`, the values are different and therefore the result of the `==` operator will be `0`.